# Server running SVN 1.6, and client running SVN 1.7

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I have a local server setup with SVN 1.6. If the client machine has SVN 1.7, will that be a problem?

p.s. This is with reference to Xcode, and iOS application development.

Answer (score 3):

All 1.x clients are compatible with all 1.x servers via the RA layer (HTTP(S), SVN & SVN+SSH protocols). You can even go so far as to use a 1.0 client with a 1.8 server (or vice versa) - at the expense of newer features (the lowest common denominator is used).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Newer version most of the time compatible to old version. Just like Office 2010 can open Office 2003 files.

You can go for it.